# android, how to grant the permission from espresso

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-espresso, android-13

On OS 13 and above the app opens the OS permission prompt to ask user grant the permission.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                
               ((ActivityResultLauncher<String>)requestPermissionLauncher).launch(android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
            }
```

In espresso test, how to simulate the user's licking on the "Allow" to grant the permission

[image]